# Asp.net Web Api set response status code to number

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

In Asp.net Web Api, how do I set the status code of my response using an int or string, not the StatusCode enum?

In my case, I'd like to return validation errors with status code 422, "Unprocessable Entity", but there's no enumerator for it.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity; //error, not in enum
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can cast any int to a HttpStatusCode.

```
response.StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)422;
```

You can also:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)422, "Unprocessable Entity");
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I need!  In your 2nd example, the 2nd parameter is for the content of the response.  Passing "Unprocessable Entity" may be a little redundant.  For example, I'm doing this: Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)422, validationErrors);

Comment: Yeh, that is it! The second parameter can be anything. =)

Comment: The extension method CreateResponse can be found in namespace "System.Net.Http".

Answer (score 11):

I ended up creating a class for this:

```
  public class HttpStatusCodeAdditions
    {
        public const int UnprocessableEntityCode = 422;
        public static HttpStatusCodeAdditions UnprocessableEntity = new HttpStatusCodeAdditions(UnprocessableEntityCode);

        private HttpStatusCodeAdditions(int code)
        {
            Code = code;
        }
        public int Code { get; private set; }

        public static implicit operator HttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCodeAdditions addition)
        {
            return (HttpStatusCode)addition.Code;
        }
    }
```

which can be used like this:

```
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCodeAdditions.UnprocessableEntity;
```

Comment: Nice and clean, i like it !

Answer (score 0):

Convert your **HttpStatusCode** to integer:

```
response.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity)
```