# Return custom HTTP code from ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I use the code below to throttle my ASP.NET Web Api:

```
public class Throttle : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            // ...
            if (throttle)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
            }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot return error code 429, because it's not in HttpStatusCode enum. Is there a way to return a custom error code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net Web Api set respone status code to number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966018/asp-net-web-api-set-respone-status-code-to-number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this over [here](http://blog.deltacode.be/2013/08/20/httpresponsemessage-with-custom-http-code-like-429/).

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage
  {
     StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)429,
     ReasonPhrase = "Too Many Requests",
     Content = new StringContent(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Rate                       limit reached. Reset in {0} seconds.", data.ResetSeconds))
  };

    response.Headers.Add("Retry-After", data.ResetSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    actionContext.Response = response;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did based on another response on StackOverflow.

**Create Class** (in controller file worked for me)

```
    public class TooManyRequests : IHttpActionResult
    {

    public TooManyRequests()
    {       
    }

    public TooManyRequests(string message)
    {
         Message = message;
    }
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public HttpResponseMessage Execute()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)429);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message))
            {
            response.Content = new StringContent(Message); // Put the message in the response body (text/plain content).
        }
        return response;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute());
    }
}
```

**Use in controller**

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()

{        
    // with message
    return  new TooManyRequests("Limited to 5 request per day. Come back tomorrow."); 

    // without message 
    // return  new TooManyRequests(); 

}
```